# Android Can we add a footer view to a content view

Tags: android, dynamic, view, footer

I have a '**ParentActivity**'

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity
```

and all the activities of my application extends this **ParentActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity
```

I have roughly 20 activities all extending **ParentActivity** and all activities have different layouts from each other(like some have **LinearLayout** ,some **RelativeLayout**,some **ScrollView**)

My app is almost complete,but my client now requires to have an **adsense** ad display at the end of each activity.

One general solution is to **include** following layout to all of my activity layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dip"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/header_bgcolor" 
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom">
   <com.google.ads.GoogleAdView
     android:id ="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

But what I want to do is on **ParentActivity** I will define a function which automatically adds the following view to end of the content view as follows

```
    ViewGroup view =(ViewGroup)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    View adSenseView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.ad_sense_layout,view);

    GoogleAdView adView =(GoogleAdView)adSenseView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdSenseSpec adSenseSpec = new AdSenseSpec("CLIENT_ID")
                                  .setCompanyName("COMPANY NAME")
                                  .setAppName("APP NAME")
                                  .setChannel("Channel Id")
                                  .setAdType(AdType.TEXT);
    adView.showAds(adSenseSpec);
```

In this way I am able to add the **adsense** view at the bottom but it overlaps the lower end of the content view.So is there any way ,I can dynamically add a footerview to a content view of an activity.
I am still working on solution,and if I find any I will surely post.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put your last code snippet in ParentActivity::onCreate and define a_child_activity::onCreate as { /* my create stuff */; super.onCreate(); }

Just a beginner so probably rubbish though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I wonder if some of the setters you are using have an xml equivilent, removing some of the need for the code?